# How to (re)tag such that migration works?

Tags: support, faq, tags, migration

As [discussed elsewhere](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1231/potential-technical-obstacle-to-migrations-and-suggestion-for-a-solution) it is crucial that a question that should be migrated has a matching tag on the target site (otherwise the migration is rejected and the question closed on the source site).

How can I make sure in an easy way that a question I want to migrate will not be rejected due to tag incompatibility?

Comment: We should probably start maintaining some of these as faq questions. The [meta-tag:faq] is moderator only, however, so I've (following math.SE) introduced the faq-proposed tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It suffices to check the following (or to make it so, via a retag):

For migration to **math.SE**: The question has an MO toplevel-tags (i.e., a tag with a two-letter prefix corresponding to the arXiv math categories). Upon migration, sometimes the name changes slightly (beyond deletion of the prefix), and [gm.general-mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gm.general-mathematics) would be removed but the migration still accepted; see [this answer for details](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12517).

For migration to **stats.SE**: The question has at least one of the two relevant toplevel-tags [st.statistics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/st.statistics) and [pr.probability](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/pr.probability). The former is mapped to mathematical-statistics and the latter to probability. See [this answer](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1930).

(Of course for both sites there are several or even many other tags that are compatible in addition and using them might be better in a given situation. The point of this answer is to highlight a quick solution that works alright for those that do not want to engage with the details of tagging on other sites but still want to be sure that their migrations arrive. Thanks to Willie Wong and whuber, moderators on the respective sites, and several others, for making this solution work.)